# boost and single-threaded event-driven model

Tags: c++, events, boost

Boost does not provide single-threaded event-driven model, such that was widespread on Unix before pthreads -- mainloop + "callbacks", does it ?

For example, if I wanted to use boost::message_queue in single-threaded app, and mix it with timers and other asynchronous events (mainloop), then boost does not support it, am I right ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd look at

1. [Boost::Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/signals.html) (you can use them precisely as you wish)
2. [Boost::Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) (most importantly: [strands](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html)). Strands will let you have your cake and eat it too (by having single threaded semantics while still enabling parallel work, on another 'single thread apartment' if you allow my *COM-infected pun*). This is *right on the money* with regards to your question because it will automatically synchronize and queue the work to go on the 'main' thread as you call it.

If you are going to combine the two, be sure to use [Boost Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/signals2.html) (because it supports threading).

Answer (score 6):

`boost::interprocess::message_queue` is designed for multiprocessing. In a single-threaded process you can always use an `std::queue`.

Comment: I don't know why you consider multiprocessing contradictive to single-threaded. Event-driven "multiprocessing" in single thread process exists on every platform. On Unix, for networking apps, it was predominant model, and many networking apps still use it. To scale on multi-core systems, this model uses multiple single-threaded processes.

Comment: I'm aware of the multiprocessing model, no need to evangelise. You seemed to be asking about coordination within a single event loop, which does not require IPC.